# ServerSocket accept() method

Tags: java

Can anybody please explain me how this accept() method works.what does it return?does it creates a new socket on server side? does it returns the reference of the socket created on client side?i am so confused.it would be a great help if anyone could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServerSocket.accept()` waits/blocks until a client connects, establishes the connection and returns you the server-side `Socket` object which can be used to communicate with the client (client has a `Socket` object as well)

Comment: So new Socket Is created on the ServerSide? @Michael Ritter

Comment: well yea a socket is created on each side thats what client and server use to communicate

Comment: so new socket on server side will be created on new port or the same specified port..?

Comment: from what i remember, the established connection will use a different free port (that you don't have to care about). So you can easily create a new thread that handles that connection and start listening for new connections on the same port again

Comment: does your answer applies for both itterative and concurrent servers both?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with that. Do you mean accepting multiple connections vs only handling one connection at a time?

Comment: Yea its totally the same. if you want to open multiple concurrent connections, you have to create a new thread and give it the socket, then you can immediately start accepting new connections again (loop). If you only need one connection, you don't need a new thread handling the connection. Otherwise its the same

Answer (score 1):

From [Java API documentation of **ServerSocket**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) :

> ```
> public Socket accept()
>               throws IOException
> ```
>
> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
>   method blocks until a connection is made.
>
> A new Socket `s` is created
>   and, if there is a security manager, the security manager's
>   checkAccept method is called with
>   `s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()` and `s.getPort()` as its
>   arguments to ensure the operation is allowed. This could result in a
>   SecurityException.

Also you can find a good tutorial about it : [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()):

> ```
> public Socket accept() throws IOException
> ```
>
> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.
>
> A new Socket `s` is created and, if there is a security manager, the security manager's `checkAccept` method is called with `s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()` and `s.getPort()` as its arguments to ensure the operation is allowed. This could result in a `SecurityException`.

In short, if you set up your `ServerSocket` to listen on a particular port on your computer/device, it will automatically accept the first remote client that attempts to connect to it. A `Socket` is returned, which you can latch onto using its `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to send and receive data.